# What UI element might this be? (Custom tab-bar?)

Tags: ipad

http://www.flickr.com/photos/fraserspeirs/4329430635/in/set-72157623224262135/

The above is a link basically showing the form fill view of the numbers app on the iPad. Any idea as to how to achieve such a functionality which sort of looks like our vanilla tabs on Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with just buttons set to Custom type and using an image for the background.  Then when they are clicked, bring the specific UIView to the front.

To create the tabs from a single image use UIImage's `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: topCapHeight:`

http://tcninja.blogspot.com/2010/09/ios-adding-stretchable-uiimage-as.html

This will let you dynamically set the image's width in a way that will use the middle of it to fill the new area rather than stretching (and warping) the outer edges.

Answer (score 2):

I would have implemented this with simple UIButtons. All you need to do is to style them (pngs or whatever), and track which one is the current.

Comment: And I presume the chrome like tab effect is a result of frames and colors? Two sets of images for the buttons (indication selection state) and how do you think is the background bar effect achieved - the V shaped separation between the tabs in the color of the navigation/tool bar? I guess the frames property can be set for the buttons and the view below to intersect and with the same color so that the effect of it being one entity which has been selected is achieved.