# Tab Like Selection

Tags: iphone

Can anybody please tell me how they have implemented the below thing whick looks to me like a TabBar but has something different from a simple tabbar.

The thing having "Offer" and "Wall", when each one is clicked, presents a different view.

Any sample code will be appreciated

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What UI element might this be? (Custom tab-bar?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245676/what-ui-element-might-this-be-custom-tab-bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a custom UIButton.

EDIT: [What UI element might this be? (Custom tab-bar?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245676/what-ui-element-might-this-be-custom-tab-bar). I had asked the same question a few weeks ago. There are two good answers there.

And google up for custom UIButton. You can find a few samples on your search

Comment: great .. thanks .. i also had a doubt that it is a combination of button and images , but was not sure and thought that may be it is a custom UITabBar.. anyways thanks for those link and tip .. they helped

Answer (score 1):

Its a custom view. You can always implement this kind of thing by using images. Say you have 2 different images. In one image offer is selected, and in another wall is selected. And you are using an image view to show them. An invisible button is placed in proper place. After tapping the button you can set the right image. And also if the images are not overlapping then you can use custom button.

Comment: ur answer is also correct ,so voting it up, but anyways I have to select one answer, so it goes to Bourne.. thanks .. :)